# Is there such a thing as a ValidationWarningResult?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, data-annotations, mvvm-light, wcf-ria-services

I have a whole list of validation rules that are either warnings (can continue) or fatal (cannot continue).

The fatals are easy, but the warnings are stumping me as far as a succinct way to set them up.  I can handle the warnings easily enough, but it is messy.

Is there a declarative way to handle 'warnings'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  I ended up adding a flag 'ValidateAll' to my entities and use that to force the warnings to become errors depending on state.